# Problemas al agregar contenido a LinearLayout desde código usando Fragment

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de agregar 2 `TextViews` a un `Layout` desde código, intenté hacerlo usando `findById(R.id.miLinear)...` pero no me salió, entonces decidí hacerlo de la siguiente manera, creando también el `Linearlayout` desde el código y si me funciona:

```
public void crearTexto(String articulo, String encabezado){

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



        TextView cuerpoArt = new TextView(getActivity());
        cuerpoArt.setText(articulo);
        cuerpoArt.setTextSize(22);
        cuerpoArt.setPadding(0, 80, 0, 0);

        TextView tituloArt = new TextView(getActivity());
        tituloArt.setText(encabezado);
        tituloArt.setTextSize(22);




        linearLayout.addView(cuerpoArt,0);
        linearLayout.addView(tituloArt,0);


        getActivity().setContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
```

Pero estoy usando un `Drawer View`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de abrir el fragment y mostrar los `textviews` agregados se pierde absolutamente todo el estilo y desaparece el drawer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ATUALIZACIÓN**

Según una respuesta, cambié algunas cosas y ahora me muestra los textview por completo tanto en los fragmen como en el menú `Drawer`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2**

Manejo un Drawer y está así (reducido):

```
 switch (menuItem.getItemId()){



                        case R.id.inicio:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Inicio inicioFragment = new Inicio();
                            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction portadaTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            portadaTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, inicioFragment);
                            portadaTransaction.commit();
                            return true;


                        case R.id.articulo:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Artículo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Articulo articuloFragment = new Articulo();
                            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction articuloTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            articuloTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, articuloFragment);
                            articuloTransaction.commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.sent_mail:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Elemento",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
```

Donde `frame` es un layout vacío que se va reemplazando por cualquier fragment.

En el fragment `Articulo`, en `OnCreateView` llamo el método `crearTexto()` que es el cual me crea los TextViews

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulo, container, false);

crearTexto();
```

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como lo soluciono o tenga otra forma de agregar contenido a un `LinearLayout` existente manejando `Fragments`.

Comment: ¿Los TextViews los quieres añadir al layout del Activity o al layout del Fragment?

Comment: No  manejo activities, manejo fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando una nueva vista al `Activity` con la línea `getActivity().setContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Yo veo dos alternativas:

En la primera, suponiendo que en tienes definido dentro del layout `fragment_articulo` un `LinearLayout` con un id (para este ejemplo pongamos que el id de ese `layout` es `miLinear`), entonces debes pasar el `View` que creas en el método `onViewCreated()` por parámetro del método `crearTexto()` y ahí añadir las vistas que desees.

El método `createTexto` te quedaría así:

```
public void crearTexto(String articulo, String encabezado, View view){

    LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.milinear);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



    TextView cuerpoArt = new TextView(getActivity());
    cuerpoArt.setText(articulo);
    cuerpoArt.setTextSize(22);
    cuerpoArt.setPadding(0, 80, 0, 0);

    TextView tituloArt = new TextView(getActivity());
    tituloArt.setText(encabezado);
    tituloArt.setTextSize(22);




    linearLayout.addView(cuerpoArt,0);
    linearLayout.addView(tituloArt,0);
}
```

El método `onCreateView` te quedaría así:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulo, container, false);

    crearTexto(articulo, encabezado, view);
    return view;
}
```

La otra alternativa es que crees el `layout` en tiempo de ejecución (es como lo estás haciendo ahora mismo). En ese caso lo que yo haría sería algo así:

```
public View crearTexto(String articulo, String encabezado){

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



    TextView cuerpoArt = new TextView(getActivity());
    cuerpoArt.setText(articulo);
    cuerpoArt.setTextSize(22);
    cuerpoArt.setPadding(0, 80, 0, 0);

    TextView tituloArt = new TextView(getActivity());
    tituloArt.setText(encabezado);
    tituloArt.setTextSize(22);




    linearLayout.addView(cuerpoArt,0);
    linearLayout.addView(tituloArt,0);


    return linearLayout;
}
```

En mi opinión, soy más partidario de la primera opción.

Un saludo.

Comment: _"El problema es que estás asignando una nueva vista al Activity con la línea getActivity().setContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  "_  Así es, también me dí cuenta, de hecho intenté hacerlo como dices y  no me funcionaba, pero gracias a tu primera opción me di cuenta de algo que no puse. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda el uso de [**setContentView()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

> Establece el contenido de la actividad de una vista. Esta
>   vista se coloca directamente en jerarquía de la vista de la
>   actividad.

Si realizas esto por medio de `setContentView()`:

```
 getActivity().setContentView(linearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Quita todos los elementos y únicamente agrega lo que agregaste a tu `LinearLayout` que son los `TextView`.

En este caso te sugiero usar [**addContentView()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

> Añade una vista adicional a la actividad. Añadida después de cualquier
>   de los ya existentes en la actividad - las vistas existentes NO se
>   eliminan.

También puedes usar **[addView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))**, para agregar el layout a la vista raíz.:

`addView(miLayout);`

Comment: Uhm, he actualizado mi pregunta, cambié  a  `addContentView()`

Comment: Hola amigo @x4mp73r tienes que usar addContentView() no setContenView().

Comment: Perdón me equivoqué, quiero decir que agruegué eso ._.' y me paso eso, ya actualicé mi pregunta.

Comment: Si, en onCreateView llamo al método `crearTexto()`, voy a editar mi pregunta...

Comment: crearTexto() esta dentro de tu Activity a la cual deseas añadir ese layout con los TextView? también puedes usar .addView(miLayout); si estas en la misma actividad solo addView(miLayout); sin el "."